# Конвертация из PDF в TIFF всех файлов в папке

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, т.к. в Python'е я новичок.
Для моего решения удалось найти код который конвертирует PDF в TIFF. Но для моей задачи я хочу, чтобы программа перебирала все файлы из папки только с расширением *.pdf и после конвертации, давала им такое же имя и сохраняла в эту же папку.

```py
    import os
    input_dir = 'D:\Files'
    os.system("convert -compress LZW -channel RGB -resample 600 -depth 4 -density 600 -alpha off " + str(input_dir) + "/*.pdf -loop 0 " "%d.tiff ")
    print ('Done!')
```

Comment: Ещё б понять нафига тут питон. Обычного шелла (cmd или powershell) хватит. Хотя берум меня сомнения что в винде есть convert. Помнится это была команда которая fat в ntfs конвертировала

Answer (score 0):

Как пример:

```
import glob
import re

infiles = glob.glob('*.pdf')

for infile in infiles:
    outfile = re.sub("pdf$", "TIFF", infile)
    #здесь ваш код конвертации infile в outfile
```